# Can Bing Search API V5 search for non english news articles

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-search

I attempted the following search on Bing Search API, limiting to News articles only:

`$ms_api_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=حج";`

and

`$ms_api_url = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=%27%D8%AD%D8%AC%27"`

and the results were very limited (55 articles) and nearly all English.

Can this API return non-english results?

Answer (score 1):

`mkt` is an optional parameter to specify where the results are coming from. From the [documentation](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56b449fbcf5ff81038d15cdf):

> Typically, this is the country where the user is making the request
>   from; however, it could be a different country if the user is not
>   located in a country where Bing delivers results. The market must be
>   in the form {language code}-{country code}. For example, en-US.
>
> Full list of supported markets: 
>   es-AR,en-AU,de-AT,nl-BE,fr-BE,pt-BR,en-CA,fr-CA,es-CL,da-DK,fi-FI,fr-FR,de-DE,zh-HK,en-IN,en-ID,en-IE,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,en-MY,es-MX,nl-NL,en-NZ,no-NO,zh-CN,pl-PL,pt-PT,en-PH,ru-RU,ar-SA,en-ZA,es-ES,sv-SE,fr-CH,de-CH,zh-TW,tr-TR,en-GB,en-US,es-US

Comment: In my question, the language is not listed in the list of supported markets. Does that mean I cannot get results in the language I attempted to use?